# Passing multiple data to an Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to pass multiple data items in one `Intent`:

```
if (strActStat == "Sedentary") {
    // passactStat.putString("keySedentary", strActStat);
    // passSeden.putString("keyMale", gender);
    i = new Intent(CalorieTrackerTargetWeight.this, TargetWeightResults.class);
    i.putExtra("keyGender", gender);
    i.putExtra("keyAct", strActStat);
    //i.putExtra("keyAct", strActStat);

    startActivity(i);
}
```

Why doesn't this work? Why can't I pass multiple items in one `Intent`?

Comment: You can pass multiple extras.

Comment: Actually you are putting 2 different data in it (gender and strActStat). You can not add data with the same key!

Comment: your problem here if (strActStat == "Sedentary") try @WarrenFaith Answer

Answer (score 6):

You can't compare strings with `==`.

```
if (strActStat.equals("Sedentary")) { // should work
```

Edit:

@Hesam has written a pretty detailed answer but his solution is not really usable. Instead of using an `ArrayList<String>` you should stick with the `putExtra(key, value)`. Why? Well there are some advantages over the ArrayList solution:

1. you are not limited to the type of the ArrayList
2. you are not forced to keep a static order in you list. As you can only work with index values to get a list you need to make sure that the `put()` was in the same order as `get()`. Think of the following case: You you often send 3 values, but in some cases you don't want to send the second value. When you use the ArrayList solution, you end up sending `null` as the second value to ensure that the third value will stay in his place. This is highly confusing coding! Instead you should just send two values and when the receiving activity tries to receive the second value, it can handle the returning null like it want... for example replace it with a default value.
3. Naming of the key will grant you the knowledge of *always* knowing what should be inside...
4. Your `key` should be declared in the receiving Activity as a constant. So you always know  by looking at this constants what intent data the activity can handle. This is good programming!

Hope this helps in clarifying the intent usage a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not the only problem, first, `if (strActStat == "Sedentary")` this is wrong. you can't compare to string in this way. Because in this way objects are comparing not the string. Correct way is `if (strActStat.equalIgnoreCase("Sedentary"))`.

If you use [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) then you can pass multiple data in just 1 intent.

Also you can use `ArrayList<String>`.
Here is a skeleton of the code you need:

Declare List

```
private List<String> test;
```

Init List at appropriate place

```
test = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and add data as appropriate to test.

Pass to intent as follows:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("test", (ArrayList<String>) test);
```

Retrieve data as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> test = data.getStringArrayListExtra("test");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Detailed answer but why should I use an ArrayList<String> and the extra overhead of creating objects (and parsing them) if I just can use `putExtra(key, value)`? Also I have the problem that I can't relay on keys... check my updated answer for some advantages/disadvantages

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                namevalue=name.getText().toString();
                overvalue=over.getText().toString();
                audiostatus=audio.getText().toString();
                Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.this,home.class);
                 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();   
                 bundle.putString( "namevalue",namevalue);  
                 bundle.putString("overvalue",overvaluse);
                 bundle.putInt("value",variablename);
                 intent.putExtras(bundle);   
                 startActivity(intent);                 
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
My mistake was that one of the variable I was transferring was not initialized.
Like *gender* or *strActStat* in your case.